# assigning variables from $key and $value for all objects in the array

Tags: php

I have a function that I need to pass 4 distinct variables to, and these variables values come from an array:

```
$pagesArray = array(
                   'pre-file1.html' => 'blahblah1',
                   'post-file1.html' => 'blahblah2'
                    );

$file1 = 'blahblah1';

$file2 = 'blahblah2';

$file1Name = 'pre-file1.html';

$file2Name = 'post-file1.html';
```

How do I assign in a `foreach` loop when I'm calling the function in the loop too?

I've tried this

```
foreach ($pagesArray as $fileName => $url)
{
    $file1 = file($url);
    $file2 = file($url);
    $file1Name = $key;
    $file2Name = $key;


    compareFiles($file1, $file2, $file1Name, $file2Name);

}
```

But that doesn't work because it's calling the function in the loop and will only loop over after it's called every time.

NB: the above is only an example, there will be more objects in that array than the two currently shown.

Comment: yep thought they were the same, cheers.

Comment: If I understand what OP is asking, he doesn't get the idea of an array of associative arrays.  e.g. `array( array( 'url1' => '...', 'url2' => '...', 'file1' => '...', 'file2 => '...'), array('url1' => '...', 'url2' => '...', 'file1' => '...', 'file2 => '...') ...)`  Could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list($file1, $file2)         = array_values($pagesArray);
list($file1Name, $file2Name) = array_keys($pagesArray);
compareFiles($file1, $file2, $file1Name, $file2Name);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, had I not mentioned that that example could be actually longer than two you see in my question. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, you hadn't. And if that's the case, I'd seriously restructure the `compareFiles` function to accept an array. Otherwise it becomes a horror to call it.